# Database Structure in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

How can I create a structure where a game is link to 2 players? For example, if I create a ping pong game and after the game I want to keep the score and the players. How can I do that? How can I link the 2 players into one game and know what player won and which one lost?

I did something similar in SQL but I do not know how to do it in JSON (Firebase) for Android. In SQL, I created a users table and a games tables and I logged player 1 and player 2 with their user name and then do a SELECT with what player won and which one lose.

How can i do this in Firebase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **NoSQL** the data is flattened and duplicated where needed for quick access to relevant data. This is called **denormalization** which you can read up more in this [great post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html).

So the ping pong game post you provided, your firebase JSON database might look something like this:

```
players: {
  -KUQvO_GBh4jdale6Pj4: {
    name: 'Hillary',
    wins: 2,
    lost: 0,
    tied: 0,
    gamesPlayed: [
      -KUQvQhApOLfhl0yzTTH,
      -KUQwI4P9q4DdSsUn9Du
    ]
  },
  -KUQvQ3_--kO67AOgc9D: {
    name: 'Trump',
    wins: 0,
    lost: 2,
    tied: 0,
    gamesPlayed: [
      -KUQvQhApOLfhl0yzTTH,
      -KUQwI4P9q4DdSsUn9Du
    ]
  }
},
games: {
  -KUQvQhApOLfhl0yzTTH: {
    player1: -KUQvO_GBh4jdale6Pj4,
    player2: -KUQvQ3_--kO67AOgc9D,
    winner: player1,
    timestamp: 1476863790
  },
  -KUQwI4P9q4DdSsUn9Du: {
    player1: -KUQvO_GBh4jdale6Pj4,
    player2: -KUQvQ3_--kO67AOgc9D,
    winner: player1,
    timestamp: 1476863999
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) talks about multiple-location updates that allows you to make simultaneous updates to multiple paths to preserve data integrity. If you make each update individually, there is a chance that one or more might fail, which then means that your data might mean it's out of whack.

Comment: Thank you so much. i think it is hard after been so long in SQL to wrap my mind in nosql JSON. So everytime a game ended, i will need to update the games node with all the info from that game and the users/players node for both players right? so if later on the program i want to display all the games played by Hilary in a listview and who she beat how can i pull that info?

Comment: Happy to help! I'll add another link to the answer above for concurrent editing of multiple places simultaneously. Think atomic operations so you can have all or no multiple updates happen for data integrity. As for the list of games Hillary's played, you can access the path `/players/-KUQvO_GBh4jdale6Pj4/gamesPlayed` to fetch the list. Then in your app, you might have a view responsible for displaying game info to fetch each game found in that list at `/games/gameId` to get the rest of the info. Another option is to duplicate and put all the game info in the `gamesPlayed` path of each player.

Comment: Thank you again for your explanation. that link you post is really good to write to mutiple places but what i have not been able to find is how to read like you said `/players/-KUQvO_GBh4jdale6Pj4/gamesPlayed` and then get the info from the other node. do i store the list of gamesplayed into an array and then look for each of those keys into the games node? or there is an easier way to do this. again thank you for your help

Comment: The first way is just like how you described it, where you store just the game IDs into `gamesPlayed` and then loop through each of those and look for those keys in the `games` branch. In your android app, you would have a view or a component that takes a game ID and fetches the game info with that id.

Comment: The second way is to duplicate all of the game info you have under the `games` branch and store the entire game into the `gamesPlayed` array of each player (where applicable) and so when you fetch `gamesPlayed`, you have all of the game data right there without additional fetches. You can use the multiple-location update technique for this. You just need to be extra careful that when you update the game info, you will have to update multiple locations not just one location.

Comment: The trade-offs between the two techniques comes down to level of complexity and disk space. Technique one is more traditional and is more efficient for disk space (but JSON file sizes are extremely small in general), but requires more calls to fetch more details. Technique two saves you from extra calls, but adds more work on your part when you are making changes to duplicated data, since you have to make sure the duplicate data across your design are uniform.

Comment: oh ok thank you again. well this is in firebase so if i do the first option then i will need to do a call multiple times for the same info. the other way around i will need to record the same info in multiples places. i mean this feels wrong for the fact that you have to duplicate data to make it better to access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126165/discussion-between-elvisboss-and-caleb).